# Mapping enum to table column where DB value is enum field, not label

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

My `enum` looks something like this

```
public enum EventType {

    DATASET_DELETION("DSDEL");

    private static final Map<String, EventType> dbIdLookup = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        for (EventType type : EnumSet.allOf(EventType.class)) {
            String databaseID = type.getId();
            dbIdLookup.put(databaseID, type);
        }
    }

    private String id;

    EventType(String _id) {

        this.id = _id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public EventType getFromDatabaseID(String _databaseID) {

        EventType result = dbIdLookup.get(_databaseID);

        return result;
    }
}
```

where **DATASET_DELETION** is what I would like to refer to the field value in the java code and **DSDEL** is the value I want to map it to in the database. I want the database code to be more compact and the java label more readable.

My current mapping doesn't work:

```
@Column(name = "EVENT_TYPE")
private EventType type;
```

Throwing

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value for enum class blah.blah.EventType: DSDEL
```

How can I map an enum to a database value that is not the primary label of the enum but one of its fields in the declaration?

Answer (score 1):

JPA does not support arbitrary enum values, only providing support for "*ordinal*" or "*name*" persistence. [Improvements have been requested for inclusion in JPA 2.2+](https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-47) but who knows when (if) that will happen.

One way (that is portable) would be to provide a JPA `AttributeConverter` for that Enum type, so it converts the Enum to a String, and persists the arbitrary String value you have internally.

Some JPA providers support custom handling, like this [one in DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_5_0/jpa/types.html#Enums). Maybe your provider has something also?